# How can I turn UTC Timezone off for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, utc

I'm using the extension below for MongoDB date fields because of [MongoDB stores times in UTC by default.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/)

```
    public static class DateTimeExtensions {
    
        public static DateTime AdjustUtcDiffByOffset(this DateTime time) {
            return time.AddHours(DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Hours);
        }
    }
}
```

All of them cause different problems although I have tried a few ways like attributes or serialization methods in .NET on the application level. I have decided to use this extension in .NET for now but I think that this is not a complete and exact solution too.

*Is there any solution for this problem **on the database level** without being dependent on programming language wtih an adjust or something else?*

#### EDIT

I think that I should an explain more after comments below. I already know MongoDB stores times in UTC that linked in this post as you see above. This can be useful but I don't need any UTC time zone difference in my app and I don't want to deal in Presentation Layer for every programming language separately. And also, I don't even want only one extra row or function in the other layers because of move away than base logic or business.

Let the my architecture undertaking this. I'm pretty lazy, the life is really short and the birds are flying outside :) I don't want the different fields as like as string convertings unnecessarily. I need a datetime type in the db due to I'm doing many time calculation in the app.

I'm using .NET now and therefore [MongoDB .NET driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp). I have tried different serialization methods but it cause another problems in the Data Access architecture. **In conclusion, I can use UTC in my another app but I don't want it now and I prefer the local time when I assign to the field**. I have decided to use the encapsulation below for C# especially.

```
    private DateTime _startTime;
    public DateTime StartTime {
        get => _startTime;
        set => _startTime = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the problem exactly? is considered "best practice" to work in only one date format (where the standard is utc) to avoid inconsistencies. the fact that this "best practice" is causing you issues should be alarming.

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve exactly? Is it to store all timestamps in some particular timezone other than UTC? Is it to store the original timezone alongside the value in MongoDB? Either way, this feels mostly like a problem of serialisation/deserialisation - after all, what MongoDB actually stores is a 64-bit integer representing a moment in the history of the world, not a clock time in any timezone.

Comment: The snippet included seems to be distorting the timestamp. This might indicate some misunderstanding about timezones. A timestamp is just _represented_ in one timezone. Adding hours to a stored timestamp does not convert the timezone - it creates a completely different timestamp. Mongo stores all timestamps representations as UTC. If, later on, some logic requires a different timezone, it can be converted from the UTC timestamp. This is widely supported in all systems and platforms.

Comment: The Mongo documentation linked in the post is very clear about this: _MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic._

Comment: DON'T! Use `DateTimeOffset` in .NET. A good DB design and coding practice in general is always use UTC and convert in UI to user's current timezone (including DLS).

Comment: I know already these :) Thanks for your explanations but I don't need them. I wrote "on the database level" especially and I wrote "not a complete solution". If you found a solution just please share us.

Comment: @gurkan A solution _to what_? You still haven't stated what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IMSoP A solution to don't deal in UI for every programming language. This is can be useful for the an international app but I'm writing a local app now. Maybe you are not bother for UI but you should not wait this for everyone. Thanks for your help or explanation but I don't want to argue about it. I prefer the using when I assign to the field. Of course you or someone else may not prefer. Thanks

Comment: @gurkan I am not saying your problem is invalid; I am saying I don't understand what your problem is. Are you saying that, because your UI is always using the same timezone, you want the database to also use that one timezone? Note that in a sense the database isn't using *any* timezone: it's storing a 64-bit integer which is just a point in the history of the earth, it's only the input and output that gives this a calendar date and clock time based on some timezone. So possibly what you want is the *output* to always be a particular timezone?

Comment: @gurkan The solution is to not use something that is not suitable for your requirements. UTC is not for "international apps". It's a standard way of storing timestamps, much like UNIX timestamps. You could store both the UTC timestamp and formatted date string in whatever timezone that is required.

Comment: @IMSoP the problem is, someone has just written a small/local app to save some booking dates... using Mongo to save and read them back, he suddenly finds all his dates are wrong and this is a series of bugs - the problem is as simple as that. He now has some untold amount of work in the app to do the conversions back again to fix all the places where the dates are wrong (once he realizes Mongo is converting them all to UTC). It would be useful to just "turn this off" and his app wouldn't instantly work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible from the db level. What I did, was to write custom setter for date properties which will force mongoDB to assume the time is already in UTC, thus avoid a conversion like below:

```
private DateTime _createdUTC;
public DateTime CreatedUtc
  {
     get
       {
         return _createdUTC;
       }
     set
       {
         _createdUTC = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
       }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what scenario this would be used in: you seem to have an object with some timezone information, and you are forcibly discarding that timezone information. Why does the object have that information if it's not correct, and why is it only important to discard it when saving, and not when using it in the application itself?

Comment: Assume that you have an UTC time stored in sql db. When you fetch it and move to mongo, mongo converts it to UTC again coz the date kind is by default unspecified. This approach can avoid that by telling mongo that the date is already in utc

Comment: @NithinChandran Yes, I'm having trouble when using both together. It seems that it's not possible for the database level but your encapsulation is wisely than my extension.  +1

Comment: @NithinChandran It sounds like your problem is in the SQL driver then, not the MongoDB one: when you retrieved that date and unserialized it into an object, that object should have been marked as in UTC, not as "unknown timezone".

Comment: Maybe you are right. Fetching the date as UTC itself might solve the issue. However this would be a work around solution for me. Anyway thanks for noticing it

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB always saves dates in UTC.

What you can do is indicate to the client that he must convert the date to the local date when retrieving data from the database.

You can register a serializer before instantiating the client:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(DateTimeSerializer.LocalInstance);
var client = new MongoClient(options) ...
```

Comment: MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'There is already a serializer registered for type DateTime.'