# Store wrong timezone in default date and time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to store default date and time using mongoose with the Node.JS but somehow, it is storing different time zone value in database. I'm using "**MongoDB Atlas Database**" as a DB server and also configured default time zone with reference to [this](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/manage-project-settings/). I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672248/how-to-change-date-timezone-in-mongoose) for change time zone and also tried **"moment-timezone.js"**, But didn't get any luck.

I just want to store default date and time with Indian standard time format.

Following is my code for the schema.

```js
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    from: String,
    to: String,
    amount: Number,
    message: {
        type: String, 
        default: ""
    },
    creationdate: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Please help me with this issue. Show me the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62978436/how-can-i-turn-utc-timezone-off-for-mongodb/62988342#62988342

Comment: @D.SM Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB stores [`Date` fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) as a UTC timestamp in milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which is a 64bit integer (53bit in JS). This is also what `Date.now()` is. There is no timezone component to the data by design.

If you need a consistent timezone format for a Date object, add a [virtual field](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) that returns the required timezone adjusted string or object from the date.

```
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    creationdate: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    }
});
testSchema.virtual('formattedCreationDate').get(function() {
  return this.creationdate.toLocaleString(); // or day.js/luxon 
});
```

If you need a timezone other than the user or system supplied value, store the required TZ data in another field and use that timezone field in the `virtual` formatting.

The virtual will probably be easier if you use [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones).

Comment: I'm also getting wrong time when ```Date.now``` is called from mongoose schema from atlas.

Comment: @SujithSManjavana: You should try this, It works for me.